# How to efficiently fetch objects after created using bulk_create function of Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, orm

I have to insert multiple objects in a table, there are two ways to do that-

**1)** Insert each one using `save()`. But in this case there will be n sql dB queries for n objects.

**2)** Insert all of them together using `bulk_create()`. In this case there will be **one** sql dB query for n objects.

Clearly, second option is better and hence I am using that. Now the problem with `bulk__create` is that it does not return **ids** of the inserted objects hence they can not be used further to create objects of other models which have foreign key to the created objects.

To overcome this, we need to fetch the objects created by `bulk_create`.

**Now the question is "assuming as in my situation, there is no way to uniquely identify the created objects, how do we fetch them?"**

Currently I am maintaining a time_stamp to fetch them, something like below-

```
my_objects = []

# Timestamp to be used for fetching created objects
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()

# Creating list of intantiated objects
for obj_data in obj_data_list:
    my_objects.append(MyModel(**obj_data))

# Bulk inserting the instantiated objects to dB
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_objects)

# Using timestamp to fetch the created objects
MyModel.objects.filter(created_at__gte=time_stamp)
```

Now this works good, but will fail in one case.

- If at the time of bulk-creating these objects, some more objects are created from somewhere else, then those objects will also be fetched in my query, which is not desired.

Can someone come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

As `bulk_create` will not create the primary keys, you'll have to supply the keys yourself.

This process is simple if you are not using the default generated primary key, which is an `AutoField`.

If you are sticking with the default, you'll need to wrap your code into an atomic transaction and supply the primary key yourself. This way you'll know what records are inserted.

```
from django.db import transaction

inserted_ids = []

with transacation.atomic():
   my_objects = []
   max_id = int(MyModel.objects.latest('pk').pk)
   id_count = max_id
   for obj_data in obj_data_list:
       id_count += 1
       obj_data['id'] = id_count
       inserted_ids.append(obj_data['id'])
       my_objects.append(MyModel(**obj_data))
   MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_objects)
   inserted_ids = range(max_id, id_count)
```

Comment: I upvote your answer, but when there are large quantities in bulk, the impact that this internal processing could be problematic?

Comment: @burhan if i make the transaction atomic, what will happen to other object creation processes, will they wait until this transaction is completed, or will they be aborted?

Comment: A transaction guarantees atomicity - which means that it will block till its completed.

Answer (score 1):

[`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) returns the created objects and sets the generated primary key on the objects for certain databases (currently PostgreSQL, MariaDB 10.5+, and SQLite 3.35+), so it shouldn't be necessary to re-query the database for the created objects.

```
...

# Bulk inserting the instantiated objects to dB
created_objects = MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already know.

> If the model’s primary key is an AutoField it does not retrieve and
>   set the primary key attribute, as save() does.

The way you're trying to do, it's usually the way people do.
The other solution in **some cases**, this way is better.

```
my_ids = MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
objs = MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_objects)

new_objs = MyModel.objects.exclude(id__in=my_ids).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: You should know there is a performance impact if you have a large list to pass using `__in`.

Comment: that's why I wrote in bold 'some cases'